# How to change the radio's selected state in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In Vue, I want change the radio's selected state using javascript when using 'v-model'.
I want to change sex's value,but it's not working

```html
 <input v-model="sex" value="man" name="sex" type="radio" >
 <input v-model="sex" value="woman" name="sex" type="radio" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize data as `sex:'man'` or `sex:'women'`

```js
var V = new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    sex:'man'
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input v-model="sex" value="man" name="sex" type="radio" >
 <input v-model="sex" value="women" name="sex" type="radio" >
 <div>{{sex}}</div>
 </div>
```